# Program doesn't start when I use mediaPlayer

Tags: java, javafx, media-player

Problem:

everything was working fine until I decided to add the media with the mediaPlayer into the program. The reason I know the mediaPlayer is the culprit is because I set the function that runs the mediaPlayer to the end of the main function and the screen would then appear for second and then vanish as oppose to not running at all if I set the function anywhere else.

Relevant code that is causing the problem

```
private void playThemeIntro()
{
    Media gameIntroTheme = new Media("GameIntroTheme.MP3"); 
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(gameIntroTheme);
    mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
}
```

Entire code

```
package whowantstobeamillionairetriviagame;

import java.io.File;

import javafx.application.Application;

import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;

import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireTriviaGame extends Application 
{
private VBox menuLayout;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override
public void start(Stage startingStage) throws Exception 
{
    StackPane backgroundSettings = new StackPane();

    Image backgroundColor = new Image("http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-p0s06MBIx_U/T8zKIBZ24pI/AAAAAAAAA7Y/n8hMZfpRic0/s1600/dark+blue+wallpaper+10.jpg");

    ImageView background = new ImageView();
    background.setImage(backgroundColor);

    createMenuLayout();

    backgroundSettings.getChildren().addAll(background, menuLayout);

    playThemeIntro(); // If you comment this out, the program works properly

    Scene backgroundScene = new Scene(backgroundSettings);
    startingStage.setScene(backgroundScene);

    startingStage.setTitle("Who Wants to be a Millionaire");
    startingStage.show();
}

private void playThemeIntro()
{
    Media gameIntroTheme = new Media("GameIntroTheme.MP3");
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(gameIntroTheme);
    mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
}

private VBox createMenuLayout() 
{
    menuLayout = new VBox();
    menuLayout.setSpacing(20);
    menuLayout.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);

    Image millionaireLogo = new Image(new File("MillionaireLogo1.PNG").toURI().toString());

    ImageView logoPicture = new ImageView();
    logoPicture.setImage(millionaireLogo);
    logoPicture.setPreserveRatio(true);
    logoPicture.setSmooth(true);
    logoPicture.setCache(true);

    menuLayout.getChildren().add(logoPicture);

    Button menuButtons[] = new Button[]
    {
        new Button("Play"),
        new Button("Options"),
        new Button("Help"),
        new Button("Exit")
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    {
        menuButtons[i].setPrefSize(200, 30);
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(200, 30, Paint.valueOf("346699"));
        r.setArcHeight(30);
        r.setArcWidth(30);
        menuButtons[i].setOnMouseEntered(e -> r.setFill(Paint.valueOf("0f69b4")));
        menuButtons[i].setOnMouseExited(e -> r.setFill(Paint.valueOf("346699")));
        menuButtons[i].setBackground(Background.EMPTY);
        menuButtons[i].setTextFill(Paint.valueOf("White"));
        menuButtons[i].setFont(Font.font("Serif", FontWeight.BOLD, 16));
        VBox.setMargin(menuButtons[i], new Insets(0, 0, 0, 8));
        VBox.setVgrow(menuButtons[i], Priority.ALWAYS);
        StackPane sp = new StackPane();
        sp.getChildren().addAll(r, menuButtons[i]);
        menuLayout.getChildren().add(sp);
    }

    return menuLayout;
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Error that I got

```
 Exception in Application start method
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$152(LauncherImpl.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$50/1642360923.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: uri.getScheme() == null! uri == 'GameIntroTheme.MP3'
at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.locator.Locator.<init>(Locator.java:211)
at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Media.java:391)
at whowantstobeamillionairetriviagame.WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireTriviaGame.playThemeIntro(WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireTriviaGame.java:57)
at whowantstobeamillionairetriviagame.WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireTriviaGame.start(WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireTriviaGame.java:46)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$53/792965399.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/355629945.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/266742917.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/1915503092.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/1963387170.run(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
   Exception running application        whowantstobeamillionairetriviagame.WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireTriviaGame
 Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Nope, it just starts and closes when ever I run the project.

Comment: Read the [media documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html) to find out how to get error information.

Comment: Alright never mind. It wasn't showing the error screen because for some reason the console window didn't appear(go figure). Now it is showing and I've pasted the error for everyone to see. It would seem that the error has to do with the URI being null. Looks like I'll have to check that.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Media` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html#Media-java.lang.String-) requires a string that represents a URL with a `file:`, `http:`, or `jar:` scheme.

I don't know your project layout, so I can't give a definitive answer, but you probably need something like

```
Media gameIntroTheme = 
    new Media(getClass().getResource("GameIntroTheme.MP3").toExternalForm());
```

Comment: How much would it matter if my IDE(NetBeans) tells me the audio file(GameIntroTheme.MP3) "appears to be in binary data. Would you like to open it in a text file editor" when ever I click it in the files section of the IDE and then goes on to say "The file 'insert path of the file in here' cannot be safely opened with encoding UTF-8. Would you still like to open it?'" Does mean that my file is damaged in any way? I should also mention that I got the audio file off the internet from a website that has a database of audio files.

Comment: How would you expect your IDE to open an audio file? It's just binary data... Not sure I understand that comment.

Comment: I'm just reguritating back what my IDE say to me when I first click on the audio file(First time I have ever seen this kind of thing). Probably be because it doesn't have any way to open the audio file when you click on in the file directory or it doesn't supporting opening an audio file.

Comment: Well at least now I'm not getting null from the URI but I'm still getting a nullpointerexception from the playThemeIntro method.

Comment: Then the path is wrong. Can't help without knowing the project structure.

Comment: Alright I fixed it. I used your solution but changed a couple of things. Here it is  Media gameIntroTheme = new Media(new File("GameIntroTheme.MP3").toURI().toString());

Comment: So thanks for the suggestion. It helped me figure out the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer

```
Media gameIntroTheme = new Media(newFile("GameIntroTheme.MP3").toURI().toString());
```

Comment: Alright I'm interested, how would I make it work for that as well.

Comment: You were right. I did jar cvf WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireTriviaGame.jar * in the command line and at the very end it caught a filenotfoundexception. How would I go about resolving that?

Comment: I'm assuming that this would also happen to the png file that I have? and what about the http link that I'm using as my background?

Comment: Why do you want to bundle the `mp3` with your jar? All media files should be outside the MediaPlayer program.

Comment: You use `getClass().getResource(...)` and specify the correct path. What that path is depends on where the file is bundled in the jar file relative to the classpath (using an absolute path) or the current class (using a relative path). You haven't posted your project layout, but maybe `"/GameIntroTheme.MP3"`, but again, it depends on your project structure.